# How to determine SQL Server version on a reporting server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, servicepacks

All of our production instances of reporting services are split into the web server components and the reports database components.

I know that you can detect the instance of SQL Server on a database server by the following TSQL:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'),
SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

However, in our case, the reporting servers do not have a database server components installed. So how do I detect what service pack is installed in this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Manually, or using web scraping, browse to

```
http://reportServerName/ReportServer
```

and the version number is at the bottom of the page.

Or programatically:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

class Sample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create proxy object and set service 
        // credentials to integrated
        ReportingService2006 rs = new ReportingService2006();
        rs.Url = "http://<Server Name>/_vti_bin/ReportServer/" +
            "ReportService2006.asmx";
        rs.Credentials = 
            System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        try
        {
            // Set the server info header 
            rs.ServerInfoHeaderValue = new ServerInfoHeader();

            // Make a call to the Web service
            CatalogItem[] items = rs.ListChildren("/");

            // Output the server version and edition to the console
            Console.WriteLine("Server version: {0}",
               rs.ServerInfoHeaderValue.ReportServerVersionNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Server edition: {0}",
               rs.ServerInfoHeaderValue.ReportServerEdition);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, I knew that ReportServer site would come in handy some day. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your browser go to

```
http://<reportserverName>/reportserver
```

Just look at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1):

The [Reporting Services Configuration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305.aspx) details the SQL Server version running.

Answer (score 0):

In the modern 2017 version, "Help | About" works great.